# ParamsWrapper in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to `ruby on rails`. I come across `ParamsWrapper` in `ActionController` while studying about Parameters in Ruby. I would like to know the real usage of it ?

It would be better, If you provide link for tutorials on `ParamsWrapper`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html has some info.

Comment: I already came across through the link which provided. But, It doesn't really educate me about why should i use this?

Comment: http://justinmccormick.com/wp/programming/rails-paramswrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper is supposed to ease integration with REST clients allowing the client to send a root element with the model name if they want, and allowing your application to access it without having to deal with the logic of checking if the root element is there.

It's a trivial thing, but it comes in handy when you don't have control over all clients specially for applications that are already running.

I always leave it turned on in `config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb` with

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Being in a Rails train for a couple years, haven't seen yet any useful (or suitable) use case while dealing with forms (except searching) or views in general, to be more specific.

The real `ParamsWrapper` usefullness (in my opinion) comes while dealing with an app API. Consider a case, app has `/users` API accessible by third parties and one wants to get user data, e.g. by typing: `{"name": "Foo"}`.

With `ParamsWrapper` defined for users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters format: [:json, :xml]
end
```

or, to be more generic:

```
class ApplicationController
  wrap_parameters format: [:json, :xml]
end
```

it is quite easy to filter such user, because params are wrapped into user key `{"name" => "Foo", "user" => {"name" => "Foo"}}`. Now, to filter given user, one would to type simply `User.where(params[:user])` (or `User.find_by(params[:user])` to match particular user).

What's the advantage of such approach? You do not need to bother, which param belong to what model, they're just matched for given model `attribute_names`.